# Mapping over IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, random, io

Is there a traditional way to map over a function that uses IO? Specifically, I'd like to map over a function that returns a random value of some kind. Using a normal map will result in an output of type ([IO b]), but to unpack the values in the list from IO, I need a something of type (IO [b]). So I wrote...

```
mapIO :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> [b] -> IO [b]
mapIO f [] acc = do return acc
mapIO f (x:xs) acc = do
  new <- f x
  mapIO f xs (new:acc)
```

... which works fine. But it seems like there ought to be a solution for this built into Haskell. For instance, an example use case:

```
getPercent :: Int -> IO Bool
getPercent x = do
  y <- getStdRandom (randomR (1,100))
  return $ y < x

mapIO (\f -> getPercent 50) [0..10] []
```

Comment: In the future, try [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a+-%3E+IO+b\)+-%3E+\[a\]+-%3E+IO+\[b\]) to find out whether some seemingly-obvious function already exists (because they usually do). It's amazingly useful!

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great resource!

Comment: Also, check out Hayoo - it's like Hoogle, but checks for things slightly differently.

Answer (score 25):

The standard way is via:

```
Control.Monad.mapM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

which is implemented in terms of sequence:

```
sequence :: (Monad m) => [m a] -> m [a]
```

Answer (score 15):

Just to add to Don's answer, hake a look to the `mapM_` function as well, which does exactly what `mapM` does but discards all the results so you get only side-effects.

This is useful if you want the have computations executed (for example IO computations) but are not interested in the result (for example, unlinking files).

And also see `forM` and `forM_`.

Comment: and mapM_ runs in constant stack space, whereas mapM needs linear stack, similarly for sequence_ vs. sequence.

Comment: @Simon, thanks for mentioning this.  I always look at my mapM's very carefully to make sure either the list is small or to try to refactor to use mapM_.